# Uncertainty in the average of two measurements (with their respective uncertainty)

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I know that generally the uncertainty in the mean of a sample should be equal to:

$\frac{V_{max} - V_{min}}{2} $

where $V_{max}$ is the maximum value and $V_{min}$ the minimum value of the sample of data.
However, what if each value has its own uncertainty? For example, I have to values:

$R1 = 12.8 \pm 0.2$ m

$R2 = 13.6 \pm 0.4$ m

The mean would be $13.2$ m, but what about the uncertainty? Will be it be the range $1.4/2$ or will it be the combined uncertainty of each measurment?

Comment: (Vmax - Vmin)/2 would be very sensitive to outliers. Shouldn't you use just the standard deviation of the mean, i.e. the standard deviation divided by the square root of the number of observations?

Answer (score 9):

If you have two ***uncorrelated*** quantities $x$ and $y$ with uncertainties $\delta x$ and $\delta y$, then their sum $z=x+y$ has uncertainty

$$\delta z = \sqrt{(\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2}$$

The average would then have uncertainty
$$\frac{\delta z}{2} =  \frac{\sqrt{(\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2}}{2}$$

---

Intuitively, one might imagine that

$$\delta z = \delta x + \delta y$$

However, this overestimates the uncertainty in $z$.  If $x$ and $y$ are uncorrelated, then it is very unlikely that their errors would constructively add in this way.  It is of course possible that $x$ and $y$ are correlated, but then more complicated analysis is required.

Comment: Could you provide a reason (or a reference to a reputable source) to why that is the case?

Comment: The reason is that measured quantities are typically assumed to correspond to normally distributed random variables, and the uncertainty is the standard deviation.  Adding two such random variables results in a random variable with standard deviation given by the above formula.  This can be found in essentially any reference on experimental techniques, such as [this one](http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm).

Comment: What about two quantities that measure the same thing but are incompatible with each other? Increase the uncertainty in both symmetrically until they are compatible and then perform error propagation as indicated?

Comment: @NilsL. I’m not sure what you mean by that. If you’re saying that the two quantities you’re averaging aren’t the same to within your uncertainty estimates, then that isn’t relevant - it also happens to be true for the quantities in the OP.

Comment: @J.Murray Correct, I mean that the "errorbars overlap", i.e. that the values are [metrologically compatible](https://jcgm.bipm.org/vim/en/2.47.html) for some common confidence level like 95 or 99%. I disagree that this is should not be relevant, since missing compatibility indicates that the uncertainty was underestimated for at least one quantity. The combined uncertainty can then not be trustworthy. Imagine the following: If x and y are incompatible and their uncertainties are very small, you can end up with a result for z that is incompatible with both x and y. How would that make sense?

Comment: @NilsL. If your height is $(200 \pm 3)$ cm and my height is $(180 \pm 4)$ centimeters, then the average of our heights is $(190 \pm 5)$ cm.  Why should the average of two quantities be metrologically compatible with either one individually?

Comment: @NilsL. If you measure the same physical quantity with two different instruments and obtain metrologically incompatible results, then that implies that either you are underestimating your (random) uncertainties or there is some systematic error involved in your measurement.  But this has nothing to do with the mathematical propagation of uncertainty from random variables $x$ and $y$ to a function $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @J.Murray My comment was with respect to two measurement results that try to quantify "the same thing" (so not peoples heights), in which case the results should be checked for compatibility. This has to do with propagation of uncertainty, but more the practical side, not the pure mathematical one, that is right.

Comment: @NilsL. My point is that error propagation is essentially taking the statistical distributions for random variables $x$ and $y$ and producing the statistical distribution for the random variable $z=f(x,y)$ (though in my limited example, I assumed $x$ and $y$ were specifically Gaussian and computed only the subsequent mean and standard deviation of $z$).  Whether $x$ and $y$ have the same distribution (or the same mean, or some chosen degree of metrological compatibility, etc) is irrelevant for the calculation.

Comment: @NilsL. If they are *supposed* to be compatible but are *not*, then that's an important piece of information to include in your analysis, and indicates a problem with your measurements or your uncertainty estimates or some other such thing, but that's downstream of the question of error propagation which is essentially the arithmetic of probability distributions.